# Hex to ascii wrong conversion

Tags: javascript, hex, ascii, node-red

I have got a javascript function to convert from HEX to ASCII and then output that to a serial connection.
However when monitoring the serial connection, I can see that the converted output is not correct.

I have this javascript code:

```
function hex2a(hexx) {
var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
    str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
return str;
}
return {payload: hex2a(msg.payload)}; // returns '2460'
```

As an example, i want to convert this HEX :

```
0340209c
```

BUT, when monitoring the serial connection i see that what gets actually sent is this:

```
03 40 20 c2 9c
```

So the device answers with a fault message.
I'm scratching my head here. Some hex commands do convert correctly ( 0340615b , for example).
I'm outputting to the serial connection via node-red.
The output node only seems to accept ascii text and not HEX.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.
Thank you for any reply!

Comment: What do you exactly pass to your function? What do you get as a result and what is the desired result?

Comment: Sorry,
I am passing the string i gave as an example: 0340209c
I just want to see this converted to ascii and when i monitor the serial connection it should output "03 40 20 9c"
But now it outputs : "03 40 20 c2 9c".

Comment: In other words you just want to split that string into two char-chunks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because JavaScript and Node-RED use the UTF-8 encoding for text, where the Unicode character number U+009c is encoded as `c2 9c`. (Please note that ASCII is actually a 7-bit character set from 0x00 to 0x7f, and the 8-bit codes from 0x80 to 0xff depend on the charset or encoding.)

Node-RED has also binary support (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/231)). The documentation is rather vague, but looks like you should use a Node.js Buffer object as the payload.

Answer (score 1):

Thx! @Metabolix for pointing me in the right direction!!
I have solved my problem by converting my HEX string to a buffer with the following code.

```
return {payload: new Buffer(msg.payload, "hex")};
```

The msg.payload is an injected string like:

```
0340209c
```

While monitoring the serial connection, it now reads the correct command!

Answer (score 0):

Convert hex to ascii in Node.js (tested in v5+)

```
const hex = '...';
const ascii = new Buffer(hex, 'hex');
```

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function toAscii(hex, delimiter) {
  var outputstr = '';
  inputstr = inputstr.replace(/^(0x)?/g, '');
  inputstr = inputstr.replace(/[^A-Fa-f0-9]/g, '');
  inputstr = inputstr.split('');
  for(var i=0; i<inputstr.length; i+=2) outputstr += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(inputstr[i]+''+inputstr[i+1], 16));
  return outputstr;
}
```